# extract data from .txt file and convert it into row and column in .csv format

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that needs a header as Id attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4 and each should be in a separate column and data should be stored under that from the document below using python.

```
image_01.jpg 1 0 0 NA
image_02.jpg 1 0 1 0
image_03.jpg 1 NA 0 1
image_04.jpg 0 0  0 1
image_05.jpg 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert(filename:str)->None:
    import csv
    with open(filename, 'r') as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        lines = (line.split(" ") for line in stripped if line)
        with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(('Id', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4'))
            writer.writerows(lines)

convert("data.txt")
```

This should work. just change `data.txt` to whatever filename you have in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Turing into a df
df = pd.read_csv('your_txt_file.txt',sep=' ',names = ['Id', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4'])

# Saving the df into a CSV file
df.to_csv('your_txt_file.txt', sep=',', index= False)
```